# Why lambda expression are introduced in java8

Tags: lambda, java-8

As I know, Java code is easy to read and quite understandable but introducing lambda expression makes quite complex from my point of view.What makes the oracle think that they brought in java8 as the main attraction.
As I am a java programmer so I want to know why it is important.

Comment: they feel their language is going to die to the profit of C# which has lambda. Maybe they actually should just let java die that would clean the planet. less bloat the better.

Comment: Then don't use that feature. Simple as that.

Comment: @Mukus If i said ,i am java programmer than i should aware of each pros & cons of its feature.

Comment: Now I understand why Java does not want to introduce too many changes. People will actually have to do some learning by reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach1

Lambda could be used to make extensible code in a readable way.
(disclaimer, I don't actually "know" Java, I'm more comfortable in C++)

To raise functionality out of a particular scope, for example, checking people, and printing them if they satisfy some criteria, Java might previously do that using Objects.

```
public static void printPersons(
    List<Person> roster, CheckPerson tester) {
    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (tester.test(p)) {
            p.printPerson();
        }
    }
}

interface CheckPerson {
    boolean test(Person p);
}

class CheckPersonEligibleForSelectiveService implements CheckPerson {
    public boolean test(Person p) {
        return p.gender == Person.Sex.MALE &&
            p.getAge() >= 18 &&
            p.getAge() <= 25;
    }
}
```

Which you use like:

```
printPersons(
    roster, new CheckPersonEligibleForSelectiveService());
```

As a non-Java developer, this looks kinda goofy to me. `Person` is clearly an important object, but, `CheckPerson` and `CheckPersonEligibleForSelectiveService` are less motivated classes, merely existing because we need them to.

It feels like the major importance that they encapsulate is the function that has the checking. If we can simply pass that, we wouldn't need to deal with the scaffolding of the classes. Oh, but looks like we can with lambdas!

```
printPersons(
    roster,
    (Person p) -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
        && p.getAge() >= 18
        && p.getAge() <= 25
);
```

This code is super readable to me, even though I stopped coding Java in Java 4.

---

Technically, the argument above isn't that fair, since you could more compactly do it with objects like so:

```
printPersons(
    roster,
    new CheckPerson() {
        public boolean test(Person p) {
            return p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
                && p.getAge() >= 18
                && p.getAge() <= 25;
        }
    }
);
```

But again, do you really need to create an object for the testing? I know some bad interview questions that deal with the construction of anonymous classes like this, so it might not be the most intuitive syntax.

But the point is, if the function is the important thing we need to give to the code, we should have a mechanism that can give functions to code. That is done with lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

I think the words here are "distributed processing". You may have noticed that in the latest years, it's harder to create faster processors without adding more and more cores.

Comment: So these lamda expressions are used for that?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/an_embedded_java_8_lambda

Answer (score 0):

To answer that, you're not thinking with a developer's hat on. You're thinking as a coder. What's the difference? Coder is if someone gave you the logic, you wrote the code to execute the logic. Developer would be that other person who gave you the logic.

If you hate certain features of a language, the natural tendency is to stay away from it. But all is good when you work all by yourself. If there are 2+ developers, you are most likely going to read and have to understand what others have written. If the code is something done elegantly and solves the problem at hand, you cannot just say you don't want to use it because of your lack of **interest to look up the documentation.**

EDIT
Changed that last part from knowledge.

Comment: First of all i am not hating any feature and yes i am coder not developer but i am just asking about readability which is effected when i read the code.

Comment: btw I am not one of people who downvoted you. Thanks for down voting me!

Comment: I didn't downvoted you.